# How to exclude certain keys/values when iterating through array and displaying on table in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs6

Have just run into a bit of a roadblock and any advice would be much appreciated

I am currently building out an application in angular to fetch data from an API and display it on the page

I have a service called "Api Service using the HTTPClient to call the API

**apiservice.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiserviceService {

constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

getData(){

return this._http.get('APIURL');
}

}
```

Then I have another component to observe this call and map the data to an array

**data.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map, toArray } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../apiservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.scss']
})
export class VenueComponent implements OnInit {

  
  data: any = [];

  constructor(private service:ApiserviceService) {}

    MapData() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe(result=>{
        this.data=result;
        console.log(this.data);
})
  }


 ngOnInit() {
    this.MapData()
  }




}
```

I am then displaying the data in a table

**data.component.html**

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor= "let item of data | keyvalue" >
        <td>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</td>
</table>
```

Now at the moment I am iterating thrugh the array using *ngFor but there are keys/values that I want to exclude from being displayed

For example I want to display key2 and value 2 but not key 1 and value 1

[Key1 : value1], [Key2 :value2]

How would I go about doing this? Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: You should review your types as well. Data is first initialized as an array, but `keyvalue` pipe is used to iterate on object properties. That‘s probably the reason why you used the `any` type as the type for your data attribute.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should use instead of the keyvalue pipe? I think this is where im getting stuck when trying to display the information within the data array in a table

Comment: This depends on what your `getData()` function returns to your observable stream. If it‘s an array, you don‘t need any pipe at all.

Comment: Is your data a single object which you want to omit some properties of or is it an array of objects of which you want to omit some properties or is an array of objects of which you want to filter some whole objects out?

Comment: Im looking to omit some whole objects out

Comment: Ok, so you receive an array of objects? Whats the condition for filtering them out? A specific value of a property? E.g. you receive objects that represent a number and have a property that states if the are prime numbers like `[ ... { value: 10, isPrime: false } ... ]` and you only want non-prime numbers?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you have at least 2 options, filter the observable:

```js
this.service.getData().pipe(
    filter(o => {
        return // your condition here
    })
).subscribe(result=>{
```

the second option is to write a custom pipe. You can create a pipe that extend the `keyvalue` pipe and filters the data as you need. You will find numerous tutorial where they explain how to create a pipe.

Comment: You probably don‘t want to filter the observable stream, but use map operator to then filter on the array (or object) itself and return the filtered object to the stream. Filtering on the stream means to exclude certain values from the stream completely.

Comment: well yes it's difficult to say what exactly he is doing since there are no types. My guess is he wants to filter out the entire objects but your comment is legit in many scenarios

Comment: Yeah I am looking more to filter out entire objects

Comment: Well, getData() performs an HTTP call, which only emits one value. When you filter on this stream, you will get either the whole response or nothing. I am not sure how exactly this can lead to a useful scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think you can use Angular Slice Pipe[1]
    
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor= "let item of data | keyvalue | slice: 1" >
            <td>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</td>
    </table>

Hope this help, Thanks!

  [1]: https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use types for your variables. It gives you the benefit of knowing exactly which kind of data you are handling and it helps us to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Here is my take on this: I suggest you to put this kind of logic into your service, so that this logic can be reused somewhere else.
I also suggest you to use some kind of reactive approach, so that you don't have to manually unsubscribe your requests.
The following approach is based on the assumption that your API returns an array, not an object.

**apiservice.service.ts**

```
...
export class ApiserviceService {
  data$ = this._http.get('APIURL').pipe(
    map(data => data.filter(item => item.key !== 'Key1'))
  );

constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
...
```

**data.component.ts**

```
...
public data$ = this.service.data$;
...
```

**data.component.html**

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor= "let item of data$ | async" >
        <td>{{item.key}}</td>...
</table>
```

I suggest you to not use pipes in this case, since pipes should be generic and your filtering logic seems to be too specific for a pipe.